# Update an array whenever a new entry is made in MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, node.js, websocket, socket.io

So I have a MySQL table with `id, log, is_valid`. I fetch all the data and start the processing. Now whenever a new entry is made I want that array to get updated automatically Right now I am using setInterval(); to update the array which is fetching the data every 5 seconds. But what I want this to happen from a WebSocket point of view. How can I do that?

Comment: Since you use socket.io, you can broadcast a message from a server, with the newly added record. A client receives the message, adds the record to the array, then processes it. This way you don't need to poll every 5 seconds for new records.

Comment: @RomiHalasz *you can broadcast a message from a server* Who will do this action? MySQL will not - it can't do it, and even don't know how to do it. So some additional push service needed - and this service will poll MySQL each 5 second... the only advance this poll is local.

Comment: @Akina the server which adds the records to the database. Since the author of the question added the socket.io tag, I assumed it's a node.js server.

Comment: hi guys i forgot to mention the architecture. So basically there is a UI based on PHP which is used to insert/update records in Mysql. And there is another system (Node JS) which takes the record from MySQL only and processes it. I don't want any interaction between PHP and Node js. What I want is something completely Node JS system polling Mysql automatically for new records. Also, Node js is on a mac local system.  So there is nothing like server.js or app.js , It's independent Node JS code which passes the formatted recore to Puppeteer and downloads files.